# Is it a good design to check User Access in Trigger

Tags: trigger

I have developed a trigger on Case object . It creates a Contact record and a custom object record ,the code for these operations reside in the handler Class that the trigger calls.

I have run the checkmarks scan on the code , and according to it I should add field level securiy check while inserting records.

I am wondering if this is good design , as triggers always run in the system context.

Comment: Are you developing a package for distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should check field level security. I hope someday salesforce might do it automatically but as for now developers should secure it.

Look here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm

> In this way, you can verify if the current user has the necessary permissions, and only if he or she has sufficient permissions, you can then perform a specific DML operation or a query.

Example of SF code with security check in trigger handler:

https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/fflib/src/classes/fflib_SObjectDomain.cls